# AngularJS SlimPHP CRUD - $http.delete doesn't work - XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, .htaccess, slim

Have an issue making a CRUD using AngularJS and SlimPHP v3. Everything works for $app->get and $app->post but got an error for an $app->delete.

I have frontend and backend on different domain names, because I had to set htaccess to redirect everything to index.php for Slim to work, so didn't succeed on putting front and back on same domain.
This is my index.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
$app = new \Slim\App();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');


$app->options('/test', function() use($app) {
    $response = $app->response();
    $app->response()->status(200);
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-authentication, X-client');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});


$app->get('/test/', function(Slim\Http\Request $request, Slim\Http\Response $response, array $args) {

    $id = $args['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_osoft_orders";

    $dbhost = "host";
    $dbuser = "user";
    $dbpass = "pass";
    $dbname = "db";

    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    $headers = $response->getHeaders();
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json'); 
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $headers = $response->getHeaders();

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $conn->set_charset("utf8");
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $resultsArray = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($resultsArray, $row);
        }
        $response->write(json_encode($resultsArray));
    }
    else {
        $response->write("0 results");
    }
    $conn->close();
});
$app->delete('/test/{id}', function(Slim\Http\Request $request, Slim\Http\Response $response, array $args) {

    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->write("delete is OK");
});
    $app->run();
?>
```

And this is my Angular code:

```
function getOrders(){
    $http.get("url/test/").success(function(data){
        $scope.orders = data;
    });

};

getOrders();
$scope.deleteOrder = function (orderId) {
    console.log("order to delete id: " + orderId);
    $http.delete("url/test/"+orderId).success(function(response){
        console.log('delete response: ' + response);
    });
    getOrders();
};
```

Order Id I got correctly to the console.log in Angular, but then I get:

DELETE url/test/22 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load url/test/22. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'url' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Every time i wrote url/ i mean http://mywebsite.com, but was unable to posta question with 2+ links.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CorsSlim](https://github.com/palanik/CorsSlim/tree/slim3) is your friend and it's the simpler way to enable CORS in the Slim Framework world. Install it using composer and use it:

```
$app->delete('/test/{id}', function(Slim\Http\Request $request, Slim\Http\Response $response, array $args) {
    $response->write("delete is OK");
})->add(\CorsSlim\CorsSlim::routeMiddleware());
```

In this way you'll be sure that the request will contain the necessary headers.

**Side note**

In your example you're using `$app->options` only on `/test` and not on `/test/{id}`.